# gradle project sync failed.Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

[this is my visual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfqif.jpg)

I have tried

1. gradle offline work
2. update jdk version
3. used "-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" in VM option

But not working. And when I check edit configuration it is saying no JDK specified though my JDK path is incorrect. 
[here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty8Mb.png)
I don't know what happening. 
Please help me to solve.....

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps in order, Sometimes things will get little messed up. Just follow the steps.

**1)** Uninstall Android Studio.

**2)** clean temp files and android studio C:\Users\Username.AndroidStudio1.5

**3)** Uninstall JDK.

**4)** Now without JDK try to install Android Studio and now it will show message that it cant find any JDK. Stop installation

**5)** Install JDK 1.7 or 1.8 (Set JAVA_HOME,JDK_HOME,path Environment variables as explained by everybody above)

**6)** Install Android Studio.

**7)** Done. Enjoy and happy coding.

Comment: thanks for reply. of course I'll try. but I can't find this. and my android studio version is 1.0.1. 
2) clean temp files and android studio C:\Users\Username.AndroidStudio1.5

Comment: There will be a folder for android studio by default in C:\Users\ folder